# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context in Alamofire.upload swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, alamofire, xcode8

Updated Alamofire 4.0.0 does not mention how to put Httpmethod & Httpheaders in upload with multipartFormData. That's why I google and found solution in that stackoverflow question. But the problem is I did same as that answer then got following error message and building is failed. Please help me how to solve it.

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Here is my coding:

```
let URL = try! URLRequest(url: Config.imageUploadURL, method: .post, headers: headers)

Alamofire.upload(
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(self.imageData, withName: "image", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png")
    },
    to: URL,
    encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                if((response.result.value) != nil) {

                } else {

                }
            }
        case .failure( _):

        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Hello, what is Config.imageUploadURL? How do you make urlRequestConvertible in Alamofire 4 ?

Comment: @Sam read below answer I marked as correct answer. If not clear yet, make a question and i'll answer for you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData:to:encodingCompletion:)` takes a `URLConvertible` for the `to:` argument.  Instead, you should use `Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData:with:encodingCompletion:)` which takes a `URLRequestConvertible` for its `with:` argument.

I think your argument name of `URL` that is the same as the type `URL()` helps in creating strange compiler errors.

The following compiles for me:

```
let url = try! URLRequest(url: URL(string:"www.google.com")!, method: .post, headers: nil)

Alamofire.upload(
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(Data(), withName: "image", fileName: "file.png", mimeType: "image/png")
    },
    with: url,
    encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                if((response.result.value) != nil) {

                } else {

                }
            }
        case .failure( _):
            break
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Great, I missed that to use `with` instead. Thanks.

Comment: let parameters: Parameters = [
            
            "user_id"       :   user_id,
            "section_id"    :   section_id,
            "day"           :   day,
            "userpost"      : video
        ] along with Urlrequest how to pass these parameters ,thankyou

Comment: I cant pass int as int type directly help me please.

Answer (score 1):

For me the build error was caused by a `multipartFormData.appendBodyData()`. After replacing it with `multipartFormData.append()` the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, after spending lots of time, i found that issue was:

I was passing `MutableURLRequest` instead of passing `URLRequest` object. Thats why i were getting this error. After type casting it to `URLRequest`, it start working.